# Record visitor search keywords or traffic source in PHP

Tags: php, visitor-statistic, search-keywords

I'm working on an [Easter Island site](http://www.easterislandtraveling.com/) with lots of info on the island, but also possibility to book tours etc. For a general idea of how people find my site I use StatCounter and Google Analytics, but I'm especially interested in how those who send me booking inquiries find my site.

I would use php session variables to store the info and e-mail it to me at the same time I receive an inquiry - perhaps even create a database for the purpose of having statistics, but the question is:

How do I fetch the search words or the url the visitor is entering from?

Comment: do your targeted user lands directly on the booking page or the have to roam through your site?

Comment: They land on any page. I will check the manual Pawel linked and I guess add HTTP_REFERER to a php file that's included on all pages.

Comment: If they land on any page referrer will not do the trick as you will get you stie's url as referrer if they come from your site's page.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clearing that out.
How can I record only the 1st entry to a page? Do you have any idea how StatCounter, Google Analytics etc do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` - [check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 0):

You have to store these information in cookies,
If the users first time visit the website you can add all of the queries he is submitting to search box and append it to some cookie variable separated with `|` or `/` or any other char then add it to some field when he enquire something through the contact form.